# Android - How to show nearby user markers?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have an android app where users can register and when they are logged in their location is visible by markers on the map as shown in this Image. But I just want to show only nearby marker within 100 meters.

Please help me up with exact coding section and all the object initialization.

[image]

Here is my code for fetching all user markers(lat,lng) from database:

```
private void getNearbyMarkers(){

    geoFireRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot locationSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                LocationData locations = locationSnapshot.getValue(LocationData.class);

                final Double tempLat = Double.parseDouble(locations.getLatitude());
                final Double tempLng = Double.parseDouble(locations.getLongitude());
                final String uid = locations.getUid();
                databaseReference3.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        String name = dataSnapshot.child(uid).child("name").getValue().toString();
                        String business = dataSnapshot.child(uid).child("business").getValue().toString();

                        LatLng allLatLang = new LatLng(tempLat,tempLng);
                        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                        markerOptions.position(allLatLang);
                        markerOptions.title(name);
                        markerOptions.snippet(business);
                        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE));

                        locationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

Thank you very much for your time and assistance in this matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween`, for that you need to add dependency,

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5+'
}
```

And you can try like this in your code,

```
markerOptions.visible(false);// We dont need to show, if its less than 100 meter we can show, otherwise we will just create and we will make it visble or not later

locationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

LatLng yourLatLang = new LatLng([your lat],[your lang]);
if (SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(yourLatLang, locationMarker.getPosition()) < 100) {
    locationMarker.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: I just had to `change locationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions.visible(false));`

and it was the perfect answer, Thank you so so so so so much ^_^

Comment: How does the map know where the users are? Shouldn't there be some cloud functionality too?

Comment: @Tamim how does ur app retrieve the users location? There has to be some cloud functionality right?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer `location.distanceTo(anotherLocation)`

In `setupMap` i recommend to add additional listener, to get all location changes in a simple way.

```
mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(this);
```

Then in this listener you just take distance between current location and your targets. Distance in meters.

```
    @Override
public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
    Location target = new Location("target");
    for(LatLng point : new LatLng[]{POINTA, POINTB, POINTC, POINTD}) {
        target.setLatitude(point.latitude);
        target.setLongitude(point.longitude);
        if(location.distanceTo(target) < METERS_100) {
            // bingo!
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget your activity to  `implements GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener`

Hope this solves your problem. For further knowledge about how to work with [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/?csw=1) look into this [link](http://ddewaele.blogspot.com/2011/05/introducing-google-places-api.html)

Comment: How does the map know where the users are? Shouldn't there be some cloud functionality too?

Comment: Yes, we must use a realtime database on firebase to have a feature like that. I'm researching about that now, did you come up with any solution? Thanks