# I want to display all markers of the locations for all the users in the Firebase database to android studio

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to android, as the title said. I am trying to display all the users location via a marker on my map in android studio. The thing is, only the last user of my Firebase database is the only user marker that is being displayed.I want to display all the markers of all users.

Here's my code for fetching all the users(markers) from my Firebase Database

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        refDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");

        refDatabase.orderByChild("availability").equalTo("yes").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        //LatLng newLocation = new LatLng(
                        // ds.child("latitude").getValue(Double.class),
                        //ds.child("longtitude").getValue(Double.class));

                        UserInformation userInfo = ds.getValue(UserInformation.class);

                        if(userInfo.getExerciseType().equals(uExerciseType)){
                            double mylat = userInfo.getLatitude();
                            double mylong = userInfo.getLongtitude();

                            String exTitle = ds.child("exerciseType").getValue(String.class);

                            LatLng newLocation = new LatLng(mylat, mylong);

                            Log.d("New Location: ", newLocation.toString());

                            //refreshes the map
                            mMap.clear();

                            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                            markerOptions.position(newLocation);
                            markerOptions.title(exTitle);
                            markerOptions.visible(false);

                            Marker locationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

                            LatLng myLatLang = new LatLng(uLatt, uLongt);
                            Log.d("My Location: ", myLatLang.toString());

                            if (SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(myLatLang, locationMarker.getPosition()) < 1000000) {
                                locationMarker.setVisible(true);
                            }

                            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(myLatLang, 10.2f));

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Then, my Firebase database looks like this:

[image: link]

Comment: I already used this solutions by the way but still didn't work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43635994/retrieve-location-from-firebase-and-put-marker-on-google-map-api-for-android and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45747796/android-how-to-show-nearby-user-markers

Comment: why you are not using a for(DatasnapShot ds : --- )  to get all the users ?

Comment: I am using it, and its fetching all users but the problem is that only the last user will be display on my map. I want all of the users to be displayed

Comment: Please don't edit answers into your question. If you've found an answer, you should post it as an answer below, and then mark it as "accepted".

Answer (score 0):

To get the markes of the location of all users, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef.child("users");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            double latitude = ds.child("latitude").getValue(Double.class);
            double longitude = ds.child("longitude").getValue(Double.class);
            Log.d("TAG", latitude + " / " +  longitude);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
usersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Or this how can be done using your `UserInformation` class:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef.child("users");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            UserInformation userInfo = ds.getValue(UserInformation.class);
            double latitude = userInfo.getLatitude();
            double longitude = userInfo.getLongtitude();
            Log.d("TAG", latitude + " / " +  longitude);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
usersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Comment: I am already getting all the location of all the users from the firebase database. The problem is that only the last user location is the only marker showing on the map.

Comment: It is because your `if(userInfo.getExerciseType().equals(uExerciseType))`. It is showing the last, but which one you want to show?

Comment: That conditition is fine, I could still get all the location of the users I wanted base on that condition.Even if I remove the if condition, I still got the same problem. The problem is that its not displaying all of them as a marker on my map.

Comment: This is happening because of that condition. Try to comment and you'll see all those markers.

Comment: I already tried to comment it out, it is still displaying only the final user from the firebase database. The information that I want to show are the users that have an availability of "yes" and exerciseType that is the same with the current user and I can get all of these data base on my code above. The problem is that its not displaying all of them as a marker on the map, the only user that is being displayed is the last user of whatever user location I get base on my condition.

Comment: This can be also happening because you are creating an object of `MarkerOptions` class everytime you iterate. And every time you are iterating you are overring the old object with the new one. So, only the last one is displayed.

Comment: I think thats the problem as well, do you have any ideas on how to work around with this problem?

Comment: To solve this, you need to use a line of code that looks like this: `mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(position).title("Marker in Position"));` See an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43216708/how-to-add-google-map-marker-from-firebase-database). Does it work now?

Comment: Unfortunately, it still didn't work. It still have the same problem. It is still only displaying the last one.

Comment: The main idea is to create the marker on a different position as showed in that answer. Have you tried to use the code exactly like there?

Comment: Yes I did and it is still displaying only the last one.

Answer (score 0):

This Code For Beginners and how to Convert LatLng to String.

```
/* Start from "onMapReady" */

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) { ......



    map = googleMap;
    map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    map.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
    //Disable Map Toolbar:
    //map.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);

    DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef
            .child("users");

    ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

 //Toast.makeText(L_Location_Activity.this,"for",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                String latitude_Display = ds
                        .child("latitude")
                        .getValue().toString();

                String longitude_Display = ds
                        .child("longitude")
                        .getValue().toString();


                String latLng = latitude_Display;
                String latLng1 = longitude_Display;


                double latitude = Double.parseDouble(latLng);
                double longitude = Double.parseDouble(latLng1);

               // map.clear();
                LatLng currentLocation = new LatLng( latitude, longitude );
                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                markerOptions.position( currentLocation );
                //markerOptions.title("i'm here");
                //map.addMarker( markerOptions );
                map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
                        .title("Hello world"));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    };
    usersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```